# Why do I need to call ISP to configure my modem as bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, modem

I recently configured my modem as bridged mode but I need to call ISP. ISP asked about the model of the router I am connecting to. Can anyone explain the technical details on why they need to know the model of my router, and why they can configure the bridging from their end. Shouldn't all these configurations be done on the Modem itself?

Comment: Because network equipment vendors like variety.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what do you mean?

Comment: Who said they couldn't configure the modem to bridge mode remotely?

Comment: @Ramhound yes you are right, i encounter a modem that I can configure by myself. However, for another ISP modem I can not do that and I need to contact them. It seems to be a common practice to call ISP to let them configure bridge mode on their side, although I am not sure what is going on on their end.

Comment: They probably configure the modem remotely. In order for them to do it correctly, they need some information from your end.

Comment: @GiantTree so ultimately it is just my device configuration? Because through the web interface there is no option for me to select PPPoE or something like that

Comment: @Zanko - Just because you cannot see the configuration, does not mean the configuration does not exist, if you were to use a different user.  Your device is more then likely running a Linux kernel, the web portal likely, simply does not display the option to you.  It is typical for modem firmware to be extremely limited and/or locked down, since in most cases, the ISP is responsible for rolling out compatible firmware updates to the device not the manufacture of the device itself (they don't typically directly interact with the home consumer) unlike a router OEM.

Answer (score 0):

ISP's usually shield of certain advanced settings because incorrect usage often means people call tech support.

If a user could change the router to bridge mode and lock themselves out without knowing how to get back in, then tech support would probably have 10 times more calls. So they usually disable access to these features. They also always can access the modem from their end and alter them just so you can still get them changed.

Although they should not need to know your make and model of the router, and just login remotely, it is possible, for the sake of simplicity, that they just flash firmware to your device which has the option enabled/disabled. Given that they have different hardware, flashing the wrong firmware to a device would brick it.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that it is also related to MAC Access control list? https://serverfault.com/a/701439/446595

Comment: I haven't encountered that myself, but I can't rule it out either.